# Checkbox and radiobutton code combine

Tags: .net-3.5

I have a page which contains two radiobuttons active and deactive for status and one status field is given in gridview. Now if i check radiobutton active then status field in gridview should be checked.Is there any code for this query?

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure what exactly your question is: but you can try something like:

```
 $(document).on("change", "#radioID .radio", function(){
 $("#radioID.radio").prop("checked", true);}
```